# Loading only some Bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

as the Title states, i would like to use Bootstrap for Web Development, however, only certain Elements of Bootstrap Framework - such as Tables.

Problem: when importing Bootstrap to Css, i also get their changes to h1,h2, paragraphs, body etc, etc...

How can i import only 1 thing which are Tables without the rest of changes to my Code/Tags?!

Comment: Download 'sass' version of Bootstrap and adjust/compile modules you want to use in your project.

Comment: Bootstrap is just a base for you to build upon. You can always write your own Css classes for Heading styles and override the bootstrap heading styles. In case the Css properties are not overriding bootstrap properties, use `!important`. Ex: `padding: 10px !important`. This will override all your padding for that element.

Comment: Hey, thank you both for your comments. I did download customized bootstrap with only table. - same issue, h1, h2 size is change as is the color etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A responsive Bootstrap 4 table **without** the color themes

Use 1 of these classes: table-responsive-sm, table-responsive-md, table-responsive-lg, table-responsive-xl

```
<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Use this css and add your own colors

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead, tbody, tr {
  width: 100%;
}
caption {
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  text-align: left;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
th, td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .25rem .375rem; /* whitespace around content */
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  hyphens: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
th {
  text-align: inherit;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .table-responsive-sm {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .table-responsive-md {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .table-responsive-lg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .table-responsive-xl {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

Optional css for printing a table

```
@media print {
  table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
  thead { display: table-header-group; }
  tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
  td, th { background-color: #fff !important; }
}
```